# mySql returning incorrect results

Tags: php, mysql

I have a query

```
SELECT date, SUM(cimpression) AS cimp, SUM(cclick) AS cclick 
FROM stdaily 
WHERE date BETWEEN :start AND :end 
AND (id = 21 AND id = 32 AND id = 12 AND id = 33)
GROUP BY date
ORDER BY date ASC;
```

This query needs to return only results where the id is equal to 21,32,12 and 33 but returning results not containing those specific ID's , not sure what exactly is wrong? Any advise?

Comment: I think you mean it is not returning 'expected' results. It is returning the 'correct' results.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What I think you are looking for is:

```
SELECT date,SUM(cimpression) AS cimp, SUM(cclick) AS cclick
FROM stdaily
WHERE date BETWEEN :start AND :end 
AND id in (21, 32, 12, 33) 
GROUP BY date 
ORDER BY date ASC;
```

This will return results, which have an id as any of those contained within the `in` brackets.

Answer (score 1):

Your query is not correct because ID cannot be in the same time all these values:

```
id = 21 AND id = 32 AND id = 12 AND id = 33
```

The previous conditions fail, and the result is NULL.

Try this:

```
id = 21 OR id = 32 OR id = 12 OR id = 33
```

Answer (score 1):

```
id = 21 AND id = 32 AND id = 12 AND id = 33
```

should be

```
id = 21 OR id = 32 OR id = 12 OR id = 33
```

Answer (score 1):

you are not specifying where he should check for those id's, and the way you pass the id is wrong as well

```
WHERE date BETWEEN :start AND :end AND (id = 21 AND id = 32 AND id = 12 AND id = 33 )
```

It should be something like:

```
SELECT date,SUM(cimpression) AS cimp,SUM(cclick) AS cclick 
FROM stdaily 
WHERE date BETWEEN :start AND :end AND id IN (21, 32, 12, 33 ) 
GROUP BY date 
ORDER BY date ASC
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't know how your data is structured but I'm surprised this returns any results. How can the id be both 21 AND 32? For example, if I use

```
SELECT * FROM users WHERE 1=1 AND (id = 10 AND id = 11);
```

I won't get a result even if there are users with ids 10 and 11.

You should use OR or better, IN(21,32,12,33)